# Inconsistent tie-breaking rounding rule used in Oracle Forms for decimal values

Tags: forms, oracle, oracleforms

I'm trying to determine what tie-breaking rounding rule Oracle Forms uses to round decimal numbers fetched from the database for display in a shorter-length field. Specifically, when a number is equidistant from its neighbors (e.g. 0.5 is equidistant from 0 and 1), what rule is used to determine whether it's rounded up or down (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) for a reference on standard rounding rules)? The Forms online help documentation addresses rounding, but does not specify which rounding rule is used (e.g. half away from zero, half even or "Banker's rounding", etc). I couldn't find a thread on OTN that addresses this, either.

I tried to figure this out by trial and error, but am getting inconsistent results. Here are my test cases...

**For both test cases:**

Database field is NUMBER(20,4)

Form field is of type Number, length 30

Form field format mask, set programmatically, is FM999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G990D90PR (that is, round to 2 decimal places)

The Form field displays the value of the database field directly

**Test 1:**

Database field value is 1.4445

Result: The field in the form displays the value as 1.44

**Test 2:**

Database field value is 1.445

Result: The field in the form displays the value as 1.45

This is totally inconsistent. If "half away from zero" or "half to odd" rounding were used, then the Test 1 value should be displayed as 1.45 (because the last 5 will round the previous 4 up to 5, and repeat). On the other hand, if "half to zero" or "half to even" rounding were used, the Test 2 value should be displayed as 1.44.

I understand that the stored values in the form are not rounded (as per Oracle's documentation), and that this will not necessarily result in calculation errors. However, it is necessary for documentation purposes that I determine what is the actual rule used for displaying rounded values.

I am using Forms 11gR2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the rules Forms follows are the same as those the Oracle database follows [as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm#SQLRF00698):

> ROUND is implemented using the following rules:
>
> 1. If n is 0, then ROUND always returns 0 regardless of integer.
> 2. If n is negative, then ROUND(n, integer) returns -ROUND(-n, integer).
> 3. If n is positive, then
>
> ROUND(n, integer) = FLOOR(n * POWER(10, integer) + 0.5) * POWER(10,
>   -integer)

However I can't see why you think its behaviour is "totally inconsistent":

- 1.4445 is "nearer to" 1.44 than 1.45 so it certainly makes sense that ROUND(1.4445,2) returns 1.44. A result of 1.45 would simply be *wrong*.
- 1.445 is equidistant between 1.44 and 1.45, so either 1.44 or 1.45 could be correct, and apparently Oracle's rule goes for 1.45.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Your answer provided a sanity check for me. Of course 1.4445 is closer to 1.44 than 1.45, because .0045 would be closer to 0. However, now I'm wondering: is it not common to round a number like this by looking at the smallest decimal place, rounding up or down, then rounding the rounded number, and so on until you get to the desired number of decimal places? This is the technique I was taught at a very young age and haven't questioned it until now. I was able to get all the way through several years of calculus operating under this assumption...somehow! :)

Comment: @Meghan That's an interesting rounding technique you were taught. Fortunately, you've provided an example that clearly shows why it is incorrect.